# How can I click on a day in the calendar and skip another day?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

i am trying to click a day but it getting an error "stale element reference: stale element not found"
i can print every day of a month and something like this but when i try to click a day it getting an error

```
        
public void GetData(WebDriver driver,String userYear) {
        
            
List<WebElement> days = locators.getLocationOfTheDays(divPathSelector(userYear));
            for(WebElement day : days) {
                System.out.println(day.getText());      
                day.click();
                ShowBtn(userYear);
                BackBtn(userYear);
            }
            
        }
```

I want to click on the first day of the month and then skip the second day and click on the second day. It has to go like this until the last day of the month.

Answer (score 0):

Your error message sounds like the element is not attached to the DOM. That's why I would suggest to make sure the element is loaded properly, by waiting for it or throw an exception if something went wrong when loading.

Since you use `selenium` you can do this with a code snippet like this:

```java
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public void GetData(WebDriver driver, String userYear) {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    
    List<WebElement> days = locators.getLocationOfTheDays(divPathSelector(userYear));
    for (WebElement day : days) {
        try {
            System.out.println(day.getText());
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(day)).click();
            ShowBtn(userYear);
            BackBtn(userYear);
        } catch (StaleElementReferenceException e) {
            System.out.println("Stale element reference encountered. Retrying...");
            day = driver.findElement(By.xpath(divPathSelector(userYear))); // Re-locate the element
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(day)).click();
            ShowBtn(userYear);
            BackBtn(userYear);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Thank for respond. i tried your code and i figure out something but this time it start with first day and skip second day but it can't skip to third day
and error is "no such element: No node with given id found.

**Java Code:**

```java
public void GetData(WebDriver driver, String userYear) {
    List<WebElement> days = locators.getLocationOfTheDays(divPathSelector(userYear));
    for (int i = 0; i < days.size(); i++) {
        try {
            WebElement day = days.get(i);
            System.out.println(day.getText());
            WebElement clickableDay = webdriverWait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(day));
            clickableDay.click();
            ShowBtn(userYear);
            BackBtn(userYear);
        } catch (StaleElementReferenceException e) {
            System.out.println("Stale element reference encountered. Retrying...");
            days = locators.getLocationOfTheDays(divPathSelector(userYear)); // Re-locate the elements
            i--; // Retry the current index
        }
    }
}
```